# How to Remove the "Restore" Link in Quick Edit?

Tags: admin, hooks

I want to know is there any hook to remove the **`Restore`** link in the edit page - trash page?

`/wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=trash`

I know I can hide it with a css/jquery trick, but I prefer to use a hook for this.

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to this: http://cl.ly/HewQ ? In any case, please add more details to your question...

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do:

```
add_filter('post_row_actions', 'wpse_56560_remove_untrash', 10, 2);
add_filter('page_row_actions', 'wpse_56560_remove_untrash', 10, 2);

function wpse_56560_remove_untrash( $actions, $post ) 
{
    if( !isset( $actions['untrash'] ) ) 
        return $actions;

    // If NOT administrator, remove Untrash
    if( !current_user_can('administrator') )
        unset( $actions['untrash'] );

    return $actions; 
}
```