# Remove specific items from Quick Edit menu of a Custom Post Type?

Tags: wp-admin, quick-edit

I would like to remove some items from the quick edit screen on a custom post type.

I would like to remove "slug", "date" and "password", as they will never not be used by end users.

[image: quick edit cpt]

I'm open to any suggestions!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no hooks to modify the Quick Edit, it has to be done with CSS and/or jQuery.

The plugin [Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/) is **very good** to hide administrative elements, CPTs included.

But in the Quick Edit box, for lack of CSS classes or ID's to target, it is not possible to hide the *slug* field, and only possible to partially hide the *date* adding a custom option as in the following snapshot.

[image: adminimize cpt]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

---

So, a pure jQuery solution is necessary:

```
add_action( 'admin_head-edit.php', 'wpse_59871_script_enqueuer' );

function wpse_59871_script_enqueuer() 
{    
    /**
       /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=post
       /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page
       /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=cpt  == gallery in this example
     */

    global $current_screen;
    if( 'edit-gallery' != $current_screen->id )
        return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">         
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
            $('span:contains("Slug")').each(function (i) {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
            $('span:contains("Password")').each(function (i) {
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            });
            $('span:contains("Date")').each(function (i) {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
            $('.inline-edit-date').each(function (i) {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });    
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

---

**Related `quick-edit` Q&A's** <sup>*that I've worked*</sup>

- [How to Remove the "Restore" Link in Quick Edit?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/56560/12615)
- [How do I limit the status options for bulk/quick edit to only Published and Draft?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/56551/12615)
- [Remove Posts Quick Edit link for specific user role? WP 3.3](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/49800/12615)
- [Inserting a Download Link in the Quick Edit Actions of the Media Library?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/30159/12615)
- [How to remove a parent theme template from Quick Edit?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/54054/12615)
- [Show draft pages in page attributes parent page dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13637918/1287812)

Answer (score 3):

Remove category select with filter:

```
add_filter( 'quick_edit_show_taxonomy', function( $show, $taxonomy_name, $view ) {

    if ( 'category' == $taxonomy_name )
        return false;

    return $show;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: This can be used to remove the “tags” field as well. Just use 'post_tag' as the taxonomy name. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/quick_edit_show_taxonomy/

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't work if you use Wordpress in another language than English:

```
$('span:contains("Password")').each(function (i) {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

If you want to use it independently of language you should use something like this:

```
$( "input[class*='password']" ).each(function (i) {
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
})
```

It removes the parent DIV of INPUT with class that contains word "password".