# How to unset fields in woocommerce product quick edit?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, quick-edit

How to unset\hide fields in woocommerce product quick edit, like tags, date, etc without modifying woocommerce plugin core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer this answer to answer to hide the quick edit functionality

[Remove specific items from Quick Edit menu of a Custom Post Type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59871/remove-specific-items-from-quick-edit-menu-of-a-custom-post-type)

Instead of `gallery` you can use `product`.

You can write the codes in your theme's or child theme to hide the quick edit section.